# Is it possible to run a raw SQL query in Entity Framework using Fluent Entity Configuration?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework Code-First v 6.3.1 and trying to run a Raw SQL query according to [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql):

```
var result = context.ProcessStatuses.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ProcessStatus where Date_Modified=@datemodified", new SqlParameter("datemodified", processStatus.DateModified)).ToList();
```

However, I'm getting this exception:

System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: '**The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'SqlUpgradeEFTests.ProcessStatusEntity'. A member of the type, 'Uid', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.**'

The reason is that I'm using Fluent Entity Configuration and my C# Entity class property names do not match my DB column names.

The error above shows 'Uid' property as an example:

```
public partial class ProcessStatusEntity : ITriggerable
{
    public string Uid { get; set; }
```

Fluent Entity Mapping Configuration:

```
            Property(t => t.Uid)
            .HasColumnName("m_uid")
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(20)
            .HasColumnOrder(0)
            .IsUnicode(false);
```

Which is defined in my Table as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProcessStatus](
[m_uid] [char](20) NOT NULL,
```

All examples I've seen online show an exact match between C# Entity property names and DB Column names. Is it possible to run RAW SQL queries in EF Code-First in a way that it considers Fluent Entity Mapping?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT m_uid AS UID, …`?

Comment: That works! @stuartd but it's a little cumbersome to spit out all entity columns. Any shorter way that you can think of?

Comment: If you can extract the metadata from the fluent configuration you could use that to build the SQL statement..